# Catalina - default color of text annotation tool in preview

Tags: pdf, preview, text-input

I have to introduce a large number of small texts into a pdf with preview by CMD-c and CMD-v from a text file through the pdf.

Each time I open a new area, the text annotation tool returns to zero opacity (ie transparent) and I have to specify each time that I want a white and opaque text background.

How to change this default value?
In Preview/Preferences, I don't see anything.

From the terminal I only see:

```
$ defaults read com.apple.Preview | grep -i text
     "com.apple.AnnotationKit.textAttributes" = {length = 261, bytes = 0x7b5c7274 66315c61 6e73695c 616e7369 ... 205c6366 3220617d };
```

and I do not know how to interpret or modify it so as to have by default an opaque white background in the text area where I want to copy the text taken from my external text file.

An other idea ?

Comment: If you blow away the appropriate key, and then set what you want, does Preview recreate it with different values, or the same values?  Might be worth testing.

Comment: @nohillside I poked around a bit in Apple Developer, but couldn't find a definition for that binary data blob.  That's why I wondered if OP deleted the key, would Preview recreate it with different values.  I don't have a Catalina system any more to test.

Comment: Yes the file .../com.apple.preview.sfl2 (sfl2 sic) is recreated, see '26 déc 14:00'

Comment: The `defaults` command also allows to `write` (for updates), but without knowing the meaning of the data it's unclear what exactly to write...

Comment: As an interim measure, would it help to copy/paste an existing (and correctly formatted) annotation instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Ok. ok, that’s the B A BA. You'r right and I have done that